# onclientClick imageButton return false doesn't work + Answer

Tags: javascript, postback

I've search about 30min about that.

Calling this didn't work.
An `alert (a())` would return false but postback anyway.

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   return a;
}
```

But that worked, didn't postback:

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   a = false;
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you placing the OnClientClick? A Javascript return false and an .NET return false are not the same. If your code is

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClientClick="a()" />
```

then only javascript returns false. let .NET know the response using return:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" OnClientClick="return a()" />
```

Comment: Don't get confused, it has nothing to do with letting .NET know about returning a value. You have to do "return a()" in the event handler because you tell your browser to stop submission it event handler returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the code that is consuming your function is expecting `false` not "falsey".  If the object `new Boolean()` is coerced to a boolean *value*, it will return false.  But, the *object* `new Boolean()` is not the same as the *value* `false`.

```
new Boolean() == false; // this is true
new Boolean() === false; // this is false!
```

Most likely, the consuming code is doing an `===` comparison, not an `==` comparison.  Just do:

```
function a()
{
    var b = false;
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is an object, you have to return

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   return a.valueOf();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in this function

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   return a;
}
```

You are declaring var a = new Boolean(); and returning the Boolean object NOT VALUE
You type cast it as Boolean but did not set a value which means it is undefined.

in your function

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   a = false;
   return a;
}
```

You are assigning a as a Boolean object and then reassigning it as a Boolean value of false and returning the Boolean variable false;

Also you can do this.

```
function a()
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Declaring a variable as new Boolean() does set "false" value (look in a js debugger, like FireBug), it's just not the same as boolean false.

Comment: Not so, `new Boolean()` contains a value of `false`.  There is nothing undefined about it.  However, the variable contains an object, and not a boolean value.

Comment: did you actually just downvote my answer because you don't like my comment here?!  Seriously!  I can see on your profile that you downvoted two answers this morning.  If there is a flaw in my answer, please post a comment so that I can learn.

Answer (score -1):

If a method doesn't return anything, it technically returns "falsey", so to avoid ambiguity browsers require "real false" to be returned. So in your case you can do this:

```
function a()
{
   var a = new Boolean();
   return !!a;
}
```

!! will cast your value to real boolean